# D3.js load US Map with Initial Zoom on one State by SVG

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, svg, datamaps

I have a DJ.js US map created with DataMaps https://github.com/markmarkoh/datamaps

I need the map to load with an initial zoom on different states (I'm making multiple maps). I've only been able to find documentation for scroll and click zooming, but never for initial load with the state abbreviation (datamaps-subunit).

My default configuration is

```
  var map = new Datamap({
    scope: 'usa',
    element: document.getElementById('us-graph'),
```

I think I may need to use `setProjection`, but I'm not sure how to use this with a state.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably an awful name for the page section, but I called it "Zoom" when manually setting the initial zoom and location.

It's in the docs here, with an example of loading a map of Africa: http://datamaps.github.io/#zoom

Comment: Thanks for a quick answer! Okay, so dumb question, but if I want to generate 50 maps, one for each state with each map 50% zoomed into the focus state, will I have to find unique values for each "var projection"? I was hoping there would be a way to just svg.selectAll('.datamaps-subunit').zoomTo('NY',.5) if that makes sense?

Comment: I'm really struggling to figure this out (I'm not too skilled with JS). I did find this for D3, is there a way it can be translated for datamaps? https://gist.github.com/mbostock/4707858

Comment: just wondering if you've gotten the chance to see either of the above comments